# Python threading: Best practice for running one thread, dropping all others

Tags: python, multithreading, events, flask

I have a flask app running a basic http REST api that has code on one endpoint that looks like this:

```py
@app.route('/api/endpoint'), methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def endpoint():
    response = ImportedApiCall()
    stuff()
    # Running this in a thread because we 
    # need somefunc() to run in the background
    # while returning response right away, but we only
    # need somefunc() to run once and only once while
    # this API endpoint receives a burst of hits
    thread = threading.Thread(target=someclass.somefunc, args = (arguments,))
    thread.start()
    # This is needed by the external API that 
    # hits /api/endpoint
    return str(response)
```

The thing is that this endpoint at /api/endpoint is going to be hit a bunch of times and I need it to run the code spawned as a thread pretty much only the FIRST time it is hit while ignoring all others while the function at someclass.somefunc does its business, something which guaranteed takes about a couple of minutes while these API hits occur in a specific timeframe. I get that I'm probably supposed to be using the threading event feature to get this done but I'm not 100% on what the best way to go about it may be as it seems like it's something fraught with a lot of pitfalls and caveats (I've gotten used to languages where concurrency is less of an afterthought). Do I somehow stuff the event declaration into the `__init__` on someclass.somefunc or do I write an entirely new event handler class?

Comment: Perhaps you have a global variable that is initialized upon start up, and then a thread that every so often updates this variable (I'm thinking `time.sleep()`)? You could then have your `endpoint()` function simply return this variable?

Comment: nah that won't help the return in flask actually returns a response body not to a preceding function